# Need advice for my career directions

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am 9 yrs old in software development have been mostly working on SharePoint and love to code and learn design patterns, oops and TTD and been using it while implementing any custom application for SharePoint most of the time but now SharePoint is getting away from custom application and since it moved to online/cloud, there are no scope for me to further work and learn the things which love most.
Please suggest what should I do or where to move so that I can continue with  codes, design patterns and so on...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not match question type policy

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft is not moving away from custom applications, focus has shifted to modern Front-End inspired/driven technologies. Technologies Full-Stack developers have been using for years. And yes ES6 is the defacto language for the whole Stack.

Yes, .Net is the Cobol of 2018 but with TypeScript Microsoft has provided a path to the future for you. (*but please avoid ES3 patterns in TypeScript*)

If you truly master TTD, OOP and (willing to learn) Functional Programming then the Programming Language does not matter.